# Access 'HTTP_X_SHOPIFY_SHOP_API_CALL_LIMIT' with Python Shopify Module

Tags: python, shopify

I am looking for a way to view the header information of my requests when calling the Shopify API.

The API documentation says:

> You can check how many calls you've already made using the Shopify header that was sent in response to your API call:
>   HTTP_X_SHOPIFY_SHOP_API_CALL_LIMIT (lists how many calls you've made for that particular shop)

On a Shopify support page I found a thread asking this same question, and Shopify's response was:

> If (you are using) the python adapter then you probably need to use the get_headers method. I'm not sure, I don't use this library.

When exploring I have tried calls like the following:

```
shopify.ShopifyResource.get_headers().get('HTTP_X_SHOPIFY_API_CALL_LIMIT')
>>None
```

Comment: What do you get by just doing `shopify.ShopifyResource.get_headers()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Was able to access it via:

`resp_header = shopify.ShopifyResource.connection.response.headers["X-Shopify-Shop-Api-Call-Limit"]`

However, I also saw on another thread that there is also an API Key Global limit that should be accessible somewhere through: `'x-shopify-api-call-limit'`